# Do we often use "will want"?

Tags: word-usage

I often hear people say:

**Do you want to go out this evening?**

But it seems no-one says:

**Will you want to go out this evening?**

**Do we often use "will want"?**

Comment: It would not be used as you have it, but it's very common. "Will you want an extra seat tonight?" ... "He will (_He'll_) want a good table." ... "They will  (_They'll_) want 2:00 tee times." ... "She will  (_She'll_) want something unexpected for her birthday." There is nothing unusual about this construction. Can you use the [edit] link to tell us why you think it is unusual?

Answer (score 1):

Your butler, if you had one, might say

> Will you want to go out this evening, sir?

*Will* is a helping verb that can be used in a future request that way. But in the above sentence it is a mannered way of speaking, and would be unlikely to be used outside a posh drawing room, say.

If the "want" refers to an item, however, you may well hear constructions like

> Will you want the car tonight?
>
> Will you want more beef jerky for when you go camping?

It's still a little bit mannered, but unexceptionable and certainly not drawing-roomish.

Remember, it's all about ascertaining what someone's future desires will be. In that sense, *do* simply doesn't work. When you say *Do you want [something]?* you're talking about wanting it right now. Granted, you could say *Do you want [something] tomorrow?* but that is not quite the right word here.

Comment: Not to quibble, but I think you're a bit off on one detail. As it happens, the event-booking person at a restaurant where I had reserved a table, and mentioned that I wasn't certain about the number of diners, called and asked me: _"Will you want an extra seat tonight?"_ It didn't sound mannered to me, especially in her thick Bronx accent that sounded like: _"Wiyawannanextra seat."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant: That is a serving person, in function similar to a butler in that respect.